# How do I restrict a deeplink intent-filter to a particular pathPrefix?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I've enabled deep linking on my android app and it's working fine. However, I want the intent-filter to listen to a particular pathPrefix only i.e. http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/e and not any other pathPrefix. Is this possible? I'm attaching my intent-filter code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter android:label="My App Name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mydomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mydomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="mydomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: did you get any Solution?